# Ejecutar un .exe desde el inicio de windows con batch

Tags: python, windows, batch

Tengo un problema que no logro solucionar. Tengo un .exe que deseo iniciar cada vez que se inicia windows. Este esta cargado en los registros de windows:

```
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Iniciarsoft/t REG_SZ /d "C:\inicio.bat"
```

inicio.bat se ejecuta correctamente :

```
FOR %%X IN ("C:\soft.exe") DO rundll32 shell32.dll,ShellExec_RunDLL %%X
```

Esto hace que se ejecute soft.exe, pero ahora viene el problema.... si yo lo ejecuto manualmente, es decir haciendo doble clic en el .exe, el programa funciona correctamente, pero si windows lo inicia automaticamente no se ejecuta correctamente, no cumple la funcion, ni tampoco genera errores.

Alguien me puede dar una idea de que puede estar sucediendo?

Ya no se que ver, leí el código infinidades de veces!
El .exe esta desarrollado en python y no tiene errores, ya que si se ejecuta manualmente funciona.

Comment: Es posible que estes ejecutando comandos con una ruta relativa asumiendo que estas en otra direccion, por ejemplo cuando python ejecuta tu archivo asume que estas en la direccion donde se hizo clic; cuando un exe descomprime los archivos de python asume que estas en un directorio temporal y es posible que cuando se abre desde el registro asume que te encuentras en System32 o en C:\

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que estás haciendo un paso extra. Si tu archivo `.bat` lo único que ejecuta es un archivo `.exe`, lo que tendrías que hacer es agregar el archivo `.exe` en el registro de Windows, de esta forma se estaría ejecutando cada que se inicie el sistema operativo sin tener que hacer uso de un archivo `.bat`.

Otro punto que logré notar es que este archivo solo se estaría ejecutando para el usuario actual dado que estás agregando al registro `REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, si deseas que se ejecute para todos los usuarios deberías poner tu línea algo así: `REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

## Actualización

Dale `Inicio` --> `Ejecutar` --> `regedit` y Navega hasta `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` y verifica que la clave se haya agregado al registro. Una opción es que si no está ahí agregues la clave/valor manualmente. Esto lo puedes hacer agregando un `Valor de cadena`, le puedes poner el nombre que tu quieras y en la `Información del Valor` le pones la ruta donde está tu archivo ejecutable.

Para verificar que se va a ejecutar al inicio de Windows le puedes dar `Inicio` --> `Ejecutar` --> `msconfig` y en la pestaña `Inicio de Windows` debe estar el archivo ejecutable que se agrego al Registro de Windows.

Comment: Ok gracias @Flxtr, ejecuto el .bat desde el inicio de windows para que el .exe tenga un retraso de ejecución de mas de 1 minuto, pero ahora pruebo lo que me dices y comento el resultado...

Comment: me sigue pasando lo mismo, colocandolo en HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE . La verdad que no si sera por algun permiso de windows que desconozca o no se. Pero no logro entender el por que, si lo  ejecuto haciendo doble click funciona y si lo ejecuta windows al inicio no.....

Comment: Edité la pregunta, revisa la parte que agregue para que tengas más detalle

Comment: Gracias @Flxtr por tu comentario, te comento que si existe en el registro de windows, se agrega perfectamente. Te comento algo mas, cuando se ejecuta desde el inicio de windows, crea el proceso soft.exe y observo el espacio de trabajo en kb dentro del administrador de programas,se modifican los kb correctamente. Luego hago clic derecho y voy al directorio donde esta el .exe, lo ejecuto manualmente y ahi es donde funciona correctamente. Por eso es que no entiendo y creo que es un problema de permisos.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Windows estás utilizando?

Comment: Es Windows 7 @Flxtr

Comment: Existe un paso más que podemos hacer, Checa este tutorial https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-change-windows-startup-programs en la parte que dice **START SPECIFIC PROGRAMS AUTOMATICALLY**. Si consideras que es tema de permisos asegurate que la carpeta donde está el `.exe` todos los usuarios puedan leer y escribir, así como tu usuario tenga permisos de administrador

Comment: de todo lo que estan hablando, una sola cosa me hace ruido.. haces doble click sobre el exe? o sobre el bat?

Comment: Eso lo pone en su pregunta: *si yo lo ejecuto manualmente, es decir haciendo doble clic en el .exe, el programa funciona correctamente*

Answer (score 0):

La manera más simple es abrir la carpeta `Inicio`. En `ejecutar` (`⊞Win`+`R`):

```
shell:startup
```

Y crear un fichero `.bat` que contenga:

```
start C:\soft.exe
```